# Android barcode reading app and saving into database

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

So maybe this is not the right way to ask in Stackoverflow but I will try my best. So I want to create small Android app which can scan barcodes and save them into sql database immediately. I don't have any idea about making Android app. I tried searching in Google but it is hard to find this exactly.

Comment: "I don't have any idea about making Android app" -- read a book on Android app development. Or, take a course on Android app development. Then, after you know how to create basic Android apps, work on building your barcode-scanning app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly new to this, too but I will do my best to help you. As far as I can tell, the only way to actively scan something is to take a picture of it, then feed that picture into your database. Look into camera functions for Android instead of a scanner, as they are usually looking for a different type of input, such as Strings. Google Camera API, and look at the database option.